# Python csvwriter doesn't like unicode

Tags: python

tl;dr I have a complicated SQL query that returns results in .csv format.  Unfortunately, the downside to being Canadian, is that a bunch of people just love to add accents to their names.

At the moment, this is what I have.  I didn't write the script initially, just trying to make it work to grab the data.  The SQL is correct, just truncated by nano.

```
def getCommentsByGUID(reportDay):
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host = dbServer, user = dbUser, passwd = dbPass, db = tscDBName)
        sqlresult = ''
        sql = 'select d.documentId, dn.created, dn.notes as Comment, u.login, d.fileName from DocumentInfo d \
inner join documentnotes dn on d.documentId=dn.documentId \
inner join User u on dn.userId=u.userID \
where d.companyId=%d and dn.created>\'%s 00:00:00\' and dn.created <\'%s 23:59:59\';' % (companyID, reportDay, reportDa$
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute (sql)
        sqlresult = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close ()
        reportWriter = csv.writer(open('%sFilename_comments_%s.csv' % (outputDir, reportDay), 'w'), delimiter=',', quotec$
        for results in sqlresult:
                reportWriter.writerow(results)
```

Running as is creates a unicode error, such as:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 366: ordinal not in range(128)`

Now, after a lot of research, I've come across something like this:

```
for results in sqlresult:
        try:
                reportWriter.writerow(results)
         except UnicodeEncodeError:
                s = list(results)
                for item in s:
                        if isinstance(item, basestring) == True:
                                a = s.index(item)
                                unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', item).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
                                s[a] = item
                                print item
                s = tuple(s)
                print s
                reportWriter.writerow(s)
```

Yet still get the same error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 366: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any ideas on what I'm either doing wrong, or what else I can try?  Thanks!

Comment: If you use `cat your-file.py` to echo the file to your shell window, you'll be able to post your script, which would be extra helpful because the most important line is being cut off :) you may also want to look at this question among others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Comment: Here's the line that opens the file for writing:


reportWriter = csv.writer(open('%sDundee_Comments_%s.csv' % (outputDir, reportDay), 'w'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

That said, I've already made it work thanks to jwodder's answer below:

        for results in sqlresult:
                results = [x.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, unicode) else x for x in results]
                reportWriter.writerow(results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL connection is apparently returning strings as `unicode` objects, while the filehandle passed to `csv.writer` was not opened with a specific encoding and thus expects to be given `str` objects representing raw bytes.

Solution 1: Encode the strings in your preferred encoding (presumably UTF-8) before passing them to `writerow`:

```
for results in sqlresult:
    results = [x.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, unicode) else x for x in results]
    reportWriter.writerow(results)
```

Solution 2: Open the output filehandle in a Unicode-aware mode:

```
import io

reportWriter = csv.writer(io.open('%sFilename_comments_%s.csv' % (outputDir, reportDay), 'w', encoding='utf-8'), delimiter=',', quotec$
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks!

Solution 1 did exactly what I needed it to.  Solution 2, I've already tried, but io.open had some issues.